# How to enable full fidelity in Azure Cosmos DB Change Feed

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

I'm trying to enable full fidelity in Change Feed by using the following code:

```
ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties("myContainer", "/pk");
containerProperties.ChangeFeedPolicy.FullFidelityRetention = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

CosmosContainerResponse containerCreateResponse = await database.CreateContainerAsync(containerProperties, 400);
```

but I get the following exception:

```
The retention duration in Change Feed policy can only be enabled when Full-Fidelity is enabled for database account.
```

How does one enable this mode for the database account? I did not see an option on the portal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Public preview will be announced shortly, you are using a preview SDK and the APIs are enabled there for users to leverage them once public preview is announced and enrollment is possible. Stay tuned :)

Comment: Thanks Matias! Looking forward to the announcement.

Comment: Matias, it's been nearly a month. Any update on this?

Comment: @user246392 I'm sorry, I do not have visibility on the roadmap for public previews, all I know is that it will be announced, no information when.

Comment: 7 months later and still not a word more about it! :(

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta can you please give us an update?

Comment: @user246392 As far as I know the feature is still in preview and supported in the preview SDKs for those customers onboard the preview. I do not have visibility on when the service intends to GA it.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta is it still possible to be onboard the preview?

Comment: If you use the preview nuget and attempt to use Full Fidelity, you will get an error that contains the preview sign-up address. Also the Emulator has Full Fidelity enabled and can be used to test. Some sources https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/9de4291ae0ad99cbf2ed8a1b2fd26b0feeb513ff/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/tests/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.EmulatorTests/FeedToken/ChangeFeedIteratorCoreTests.cs#L691